# odoo js error while modifying function, property 'include' undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, odoo-10

I have modified a js function of odoo website. The code looks like below -

```
odoo.define('website_custom_menu.menu_custom', function (require) {
    'use strict';
    require('website.contentMenu');
    var EditMenuDialog = require('website.contentMenu').EditMenuDialog;
    EditMenuDialog.include({
        start: function () {
            this._super();
            var r = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            this.$('.oe_menu_editor').nestedSortable({
                listType: 'ul',
                handle: 'div',
                items: 'li',
                maxLevels: 4,
                toleranceElement: '> div',
                forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                opacity: 0.6,
                placeholder: 'oe_menu_placeholder',
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                attribute: 'data-menu-id',
                expression: '()(.+)'
            });
            return r;
        }
    });
});
```

This modifies the website menu editor. Where it can be edited to put four levels of submenus. But this throws an error on the consloe.

It says "Failed Module" while loading it. And after some debugging on the console I found following error:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'include' of undefined
>     at website.assets_editor.js:191
>     at process_job (web.assets_common.js:2994)
>     at Object.process_jobs (web.assets_common.js:3000)
>     at $.when.then.job.rejected (web.assets_common.js:2995)
>     at web.assets_common.js:547
>     at fire (web.assets_common.js:541)
>     at Object.add as done
>     at Array. (web.assets_common.js:547)
>     at Function.each (web.assets_common.js:370)
>     at Object. (web.assets_common.js:547)
> ```

How do I fix that and what causes this? I have seen other modules and they have done it in the same way.

TBN: The module has the website module as dependency and the js file is added in the assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EditMenuDialog is undefined because **/website/static/src/js/website.contentMenu.js** which defines *website.contentMenu* returns only TopBar

```
return {
    'TopBar': TopBarContent,
};
```

You can add EditMenuDialog to it:

```
return {
    'TopBar': TopBarContent,
    'EditMenuDialog': EditMenuDialog,
};
```

Comment: 'include' property is undefined not EditMenuDialog. In the EditMenuDialog I am calling super and returning 'r'. I don't think I need to return the way you have shown.

Comment: @Lucas is right. Refer the updated version https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/website/static/src/js/website.contentMenu.js

Comment: var contentMenu = require('website.contentMenu');  contentMenu.EditMenuDialog.include({    start: function () { }  });

Comment: so, this isn't possible to return EditMenuDialog from my js to the main website.contentmenu.js . I don't want to edit the main addon file.

Answer (score 0):

your code has a bug, make this call:

```
var EditMenuDialog = require('website.contentMenu').EditMenuDialog;
```

following module manager in odoo, require will give an instance then you can extende/include try:

```
var EditMenuDialog = require('website.contentMenu.EditMenuDialog');
```

If EditMenuDialog is a module.

You can check our example [here](https://github.com/odoo-ecuador/odoo-ecuador/blob/10.0/l10n_ec_pos/static/src/js/pos.js)

Also on odoo source code you can check more examples with same [hacks](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/search?l=JavaScript&q=contentmenu&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

[examples](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/search?l=JavaScript&q=contentmenu&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: var EditMenuDialog = require('website.contentMenu.EditMenuDialog'); this will throw an error of dependency.

I have tried the solution by looking at the codes in odoo. I also found an interesting thing - if you run the code in odoo 10 latest code, you will not see the error. If you run the code with 2016 odoo 10 code, you will see the failed module error shows in console.

I also tried using this var EditMenuDialog = require('website.contentMenu') and later extending it but the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

You should use extend instead of include for EditMenuDialog.

**Hint:**

```
odoo.define('website_custom_menu.menu_custom', function (require) {
'use strict';
    var widget = require('web_editor.widget');
    var MyMenuDialog = require('website.contentMenu');
    MyMenuDialog.EditMenuDialog.extend({
        start: function () {
            this._super();
            var r = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            this.$('.oe_menu_editor').nestedSortable({
                listType: 'ul',
                handle: 'div',
                items: 'li',
                maxLevels: 4,
                toleranceElement: '> div',
                forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                opacity: 0.6,
                placeholder: 'oe_menu_placeholder',
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                attribute: 'data-menu-id',
                expression: '()(.+)'
            });
            return r;
        }
    });
    return MyMenuDialog;
});
```

Comment: it's the same. In case of extend it gives this error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

Comment: @Tanzil Khan you need to do changes in the XML file that includes JavaScript file path with " inherite_id --> website.assets_editor " instead of assets_backend.

Comment: I have done that. But that is not the issue. I found it is an odoo bug.

Comment: yes there is odoo bug because it isn't return EditMenuDialog.